# Can I use a metal bowl with rubber bottom as double boiler?

Tags: melting-chocolate

So long story short I am attempting to make some chocolate covered strawberries for my wife for mother's day tomorrow. I found some easy recipes that I want to try, including one that say you can just melt the chips in the microwave, like [this](https://www.thespruceeats.com/chocolate-covered-strawberries-520809). After only two rounds of 30 seconds the batch I put in microwave was starting to burn, granted I did only use a smaller amount to test it and avoid ruining my whole pack of pieces...

Due to this I started looking for make shift double boiler ideas I can use and I found one that mentions using a pot with a metal bowl on top. So like this I will be able to stir everything the entire time and it sounds promising but the only bowls we have are like [these](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/614dluZ1Q%2BL._SX425_.jpg) with rubber bottoms...

Can I use these bowls for my make shift double boilder? If this is not safe or advisable is there any other tips you guys have that could help out a noob cook trying to be sweet?!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think I found something this morning after starting to scour the internet again for an answer. I don't know if it applies to all bowls, but [this link](https://img.hsni.com/images/content/pdf/542081_PRODUCTMANUAL.pdf) applies to my bowl at least. In the bottom left of the second page it straight up addresses using the bowl as a double boiler! Not sure how I never found this yesterday... Mission accomplished.